# Refreshing pytest fixtures in first test during custom scenario runner

Tags: python, pytest

I implemented [scenario support](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/example/parametrize.html#a-quick-port-of-testscenarios) for my pytest-based tests, and it works well.

However, one of my fixtures initialises the database with clean tables, and the second scenario runs the test with a dirty database. How can I get the database fixture re-initialised or refreshed in subsequent scenarios?

To be clear, I want to see this:

- scenario 1

  - `test_demo1` gets a fresh DB, and the test writes to the DB
  - `test_demo2` does not re-init the DB, but sees the changes made by `test_demo1`
- scenario 2

  - `test_demo1` gets a fresh DB again, and the test writes to the DB
  - `test_demo2` does not re-init the DB, but sees the changes made by `test_demo1` only in scenario 2.

```py
def pytest_runtest_setup(item):
    if hasattr(item.cls, "scenarios") and "first" in item.keywords:
        # what to do here?

@pytest.mark.usefixtures("db")
class TestSampleWithScenarios:
    scenarios = [scenario1, scenario2]

    @pytest.mark.first
    def test_demo1(self, db):
        # db is dirty here in scenario2
        pass

    def test_demo2(self, db):
        pass
```

I'm currently digging through the pytest sources to find an answer and I will post here once I have something.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen I've added an update ("To be clear"). I'll also make some example code (coming soon).

Comment: Thanks! One problem I see here is the order the tests are executed in. In your example you get `test_demo1[scenario1] - test_demo1[scenario2] - test_demo2[scenario1] - test_demo2[scenario2]`, meaning that both `first` tests will be executed before the other tests, but you need `test_demo1[scenario1] - test_demo2[scenario1]...` in order for the DB reset to work as intended. Or did you already change the order in `pytest_generate_tests`?

Comment: Yes, the order is already changed by the [scenario support](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/example/parametrize.html#a-quick-port-of-testscenarios) I've implemented.

Comment: Ah, ok, so that's not a problem. Can you adapt the `db` fixture for this, or is it used elsewhere?

Comment: Can be adapted, yes :)

Answer (score 1):

I've found a workaround. Have a regular test which uses the DB fixture, `parametrize` with the scenarios, and call the tests in the class directly:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize(["scenario"], scenarios)
def test_sample_with_scenarios(db, scenario):
    TestSampleWithScenarios().test_demo1(db, scenario)
    TestSampleWithScenarios().test_demo2(db, scenario)
```

Comment: Nice! I had another workaround - checking `first` mark in the db fixture, but yours does not depend on the test order, so it is cleaner.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen Thanks for the time you spent on this :-)